# Correct way to 'glue' two class implementation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++, now I have a problem needs to solve. I have a class in A library and the same class in B library, C function is the only connection between A and B, I need to pass the class implemented in A and run it in B, what is the best way to do it in C function?
In library A

```
class ClassAImp : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassAImp();
    ~ClassAImp();
    
    void Setup() override {/* do some setup */};
    void TearDown() override {/* do teardown stuff */};
    void runMethodA(void* ptr) override {/* do method A stuff */};
}

class ClassA
{
public:    
    virtual void Setup() = 0;
    virtual TearDown() = 0;
    virtual runMethodA(void* ptr) = 0;
}
```

In library B

```
class ClassB
{
public:    
    virtual void Setup() = 0;
    virtual TearDown() = 0;
    virtual runMethodA(void* ptr) = 0;
}
```

Currently what I am doing in C is

```
class ClassBImp : public ClassB
{
public:
    ClassBImp(std::shared_ptr<ClassA> _classAObj) : classAObj(_classAObj) {};
    virtual ~ClassBImp();
    
    void Setup() override { if (classAObj) classAObj->Setup(); };
    void TearDown() override { if (classAObj) classAObj->TearDown(); };
    void runMethodA(void* ptr) override { if (classAObj) classAObj->runMethodA(ptr); };
private:
    std::shared_ptr<ClassA> classAObj;
}
```

And pass the ClassBImpPtr (as std::shared_ptr) to the B library.

I don't have any control over library A or B, only can do things in C and pass the implemented object back to B. Is it the right way of doing things in C++ (11?) Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: it'd be simpler to enforce that `ClassAPtr` is non-null

Comment: @MooingDuck Would you be able to clarify it more? I am not really understand it. Edit: you must mean the `if (classAObj)` bits, yeah, sure.

Comment: `ClassB`  is missing a virtual destructor

Comment: `ClassBImpl(ClassA & a) : classAObj(&a) {}`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number and `ClassA`, but that's a library A and library B problem

Comment: what do you mean with "better" ? the code looks ok. If it does what it should do, whats the problem? What makes you think it needs to be "better" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number As a beginner, I always worries that this is not the 'right' way of doing things, or there is a more elegant way of solving it.

Comment: Library A is handing you a `ClassAImpl` object (via a `ClassAPtr`)?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, it is actually a `std::shared_ptr<>`

Comment: What is `ClassBImplPtr`  and `ClassAPtr` ? If those are raw pointers, then thats something to be improved, but might also be restricted by the libraries you are using

Comment: and `Setup` and `Teardown` sound like they actually want to be constructors and destructors, maybe writing a complete new wrapper for both `A` and `B`  can be more "elegant"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry about my typo, I will fix that.

Comment: So (a) your code doesn't actually compile, (b) your code is abstract for little reason.  "C" is mentioned in the description but not in the code.  Libraries and classes are using the same set of names ("A" refers to both a class and a library?).  It is unclear what your classes represent; do you believe that code can only exist in classes?  It is unclear how your libraries are related.  Is this static or dynamic?  Why does ClassB not inherit from ClassA?  (there are many good reasons, but none listed above).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are getting an already constructed `ClassAImpl` object, this is about as good as it gets.

Comment: This doesn't work, because `ClassBImpl` doesn't define overrides for the pure virtual `ClassB` functions like `ClassB::Setup()`. It doesn't matter that they look the same as the ones in `ClassAImpl`. They're still different functions.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be that library A and library B would use type erasure, so they would accept any type without having inheritance.

If you can't do that, you can write adaptators for the libraries:

```
template<typename T>
struct AdaptatorClassA : ClassA {
    AdaptatorClassA(T object) : object{std::move(object)} {}
    
    void Setup() override {
        object.Setup();
    }

    void TearDown() override {
        object.TearDown();
    }

    void runMethodA(void* ptr) override {
        object.runMethodA(ptr);
    }

private:
    T object;
};

template<typename T>
auto makeAdaptatorClassA(T obj) -> AdaptatorClassA {
    return AdaptatorClassA<T>{std::move(obj)};
}

template<typename T>
struct AdaptatorClassB : ClassB {
    AdaptatorClassB(T object) : object{std::move(object} {}
    
    void Setup() override {
        object.Setup();
    }

    void TearDown() override {
        object.TearDown();
    }

    void runMethodA(void* ptr) override {
        object.runMethodA(ptr);
    }

private:
    T object;
};

template<typename T>
auto makeAdaptatorClassB(T obj) -> AdaptatorClassB {
    return AdaptatorClassB<T>{std::move(obj)};
}
```

Then using this you can have any types working with `ClassB`, as long as the type has the 3 function declared:

```
struct MyClassThatWorksWithBoth { // <==== No inheritance, use adaptators
    void Setup() {/* do some setup */}
    void TearDown() {/* do teardown stuff */}
    void runMethodA(void*) {/* do method A stuff */}
};
```

You can then send that type to both libraries using the adaptators:

```
auto C() -> void {
    auto c = MyClassThatWorksWithBoth{};

    auto a = makeAdaptatorClassA(c);
    auto b = makeAdaptatorClassB(c);

    // call library A and library B with both a and b
}
```

Of course, if needed, you can make the adaptators contain pointer so you can send the same instance of `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth` to both libraries.

Note that using adaptators you won't need to make type have multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, I would also take a look at the type erasure (prepare for the future.)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, preferably with code? Do the member functions of `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth` serve any purpose? Are they meant as placeholders filled with anything? With what? Also, in `auto makeAdaptatorClassA(T obj) -> AdaptatorClassA {` the type argument to `AdaptatorClassA ` is missing; I assume it would be `T`, i.e., `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth`? Also, you say `// call library A and library B with both a and b` but I cannot see how you call `classB`'s functions through `a`. What am I missing?

Comment: They are placeholder, just as an example of a class implementing the interface. I could change that

Comment: I was asking because your code never calls any of `ClassA` or `ClassB` member functions. It only calls `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth` members which are unrelated, except for their names which happen to be identical. Shouldn't the `AdaptatorClassB` template be instantiated with `ClassBImp` (and not with `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth`)? Or maybe `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth` should be a template that gets instantiated with one of the  `ClassAImp` or `ClassBImp` (which still needs to be written) type parameters and forwards calls to those implementations?

Comment: Also it seems to me that `AdaptatorClassA` and `AdaptatorClassB` should get a second type parameter for `ClassA` or  `ClassB`  and inherit from that, folding both class definitions into one.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I assumed that just like OP, `A` library and `B` library have function that needs a `ClassA` and `ClassB` respectively and the libraries are gonna call the functions.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica you can notice that in OP's code in the question, there is no code that actually calls any of the function of `ClassA` or `ClassB`. Yes you would need to create some `ClassAImp` or `ClassBImp` or in my example, `MyClassThatWorksWithBoth` then send this type to both liraries.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are unhappy about the code duplication (stupid repetitions!). Some duplication is unavoidable with delegation (here: Let an existing implementation — `ClassBImp` — do another interface's —  `ClassA`'s — job).

But if you simply inherit from both the interface and the implementation you don't have to create a separate `ClassAImp` object — your class *[is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a#C++)* `ClassB` —, and the forwarding is arguably simpler because you just qualify the function you call to do the work with the implementation class name:

```
struct ClassBImp: public ClassAImp, public ClassB
{
    void Setup() override { ClassAImp::Setup(); }
    void TearDown()  override { ClassAImp::TearDown(); }
    void runMethod(void* ptr)  override { ClassAImp::runMethod(ptr); }
};
```

It doesn't get any simpler than that.

Let's assume a function in Library B which expects a shared pointer to a `ClassB` (and I further assume that this function most likely calls member functions of the `ClassB` object we passed a pointer to):

```
static void Library_B_Callback(std::shared_ptr<ClassB> bPtr) 
{ 
    std::cout << "DoSomething<std::shared_ptr<ClassB>>\n"; 
    if (bPtr)
    {
        std::cout << "DoSomething<std::shared_ptr<ClassB>>: Calling bPtr->runMethod()\n";
        // do something with that pointer
        bPtr->runMethod(nullptr);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with

```
int main()
{
    Library_B_Callback(make_shared<ClassBImp>());
}
```

That is, you can provide a shared pointer to a derived when a shared pointer to base is expected, just like regular pointers; they are covariant.

Comment: I just realized that this assumes that `ClassAImp` is visible for the user. If the public interface of library A only contains the abstract `ClassA` and its implementation is hidden, you cannot use it, obviously. Similarly, if the ClassAImp cannot simply be default-constructed but needs some library magic upon creation, you have to use the object from the library.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after I started to modify my code, currently the ClassA is implemented by the library and I only got the pointer to its instance. Thanks for your help, it is always good to learn more.

Comment: In that case your solution to use that pointer is proper. You can still inherit both from ClassA and ClassB though if that's convenient (for example, if Library A also has a function expecting a ClassA pointer, symmetrically to the function in ClassB). I'll amend my answer.